# iptables rules for a transparent squid2.7 proxy, and a single network interface

Tags: iptables, squid

I want to use Squid 2.7 as a transparent caching proxy for HTTP traffic on a Raspberry Pi running Debian Linux. The raspberry pi will be connected to my wifi router (MBR1400) using a single network interface.

I've already set up Squid and it works great from other computers, as long as I specify the Proxy Configuration manually, such as:

`curl --proxy 192.168.0.250:3128 http://google.com`

This also works correctly if I instruct Chrome, Firefox, or OS X to use the correct proxy ip, 192.168.0.250.

The trouble comes when I try to make it "transparent."

I've tried to make it transparent by configuring adding a static route to the router so that all traffic will pass through the Squid box. And then use `iptables` on the Squid box to redirect port 80 traffic to port 3128.

Detailed steps

1) Add a static route to my router

```
IPv4 (v6 has been disabled)
IP Address: 192.168.0.1
Netmask:    255.255.255.128
Gateway:    192.168.0.250
METRIC:     1
```

This shows a routing table of

```
IP            GW              Metric 
192.168.0.0   192.168.0.250   1      # mine
192.168.0.0                   0      # system default
# plus some other routes that I don't think are important
```

2) add iptables rules on the squid box

```
# clear existing iptables rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables --table nat -F
iptables --table nat -X
iptables --table mangle -F
iptables --table mangle -X

# the rest of these rules were adapted from a blog post and I don't fully understand how they work
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.250:3128
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.250 -p tcp -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.1
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.250 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

Am I on the right track?
Does the static route look correct?
What is wrong with my `iptables` rules?

Answer (score 0):

Does the router know how to reach the proxy? As the proxy is not in the routers network 192.168.0.0/25 (Netmask: 255.255.255.128 => 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.127). You should have a second interface with the related address so the router can route it there.